# Cannot find Test Explorer in MS VS2013

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Just trying to create a test project did absolutely nothing!  From the [MS site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385(v=vs.120).aspx#objectRef) (I did everything under **To link the tests to the object or library files**):

## Run the tests

1. On the View menu, choose Other Windows, Test Explorer. ***WTF?!?!***

I'm done before I even start.  I can't find this option.  Listed options are:

```
Command Window
Web Browser
Page Inspector
--------------------------------------------
Test Results
Source Control Explorer
--------------------------------------------
Data Tools Operations
Package Manger Console
Web Publish Activity
ShelveSetComparer
Image Watch
Browser Link Dashboard
Document Outline
History
Pending Changes
Properties Window
Server Explorer
Task List
F# Interactive
--------------------------------------------
Code Analysis
Code Metrics Results.
```

Nowhere is there Test Explorer. :( What am I missing?

Comment: It might be in the TEST menu instead of VIEW.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely "Test - Windows". Notice you don't have other stuff like "breakpoints", because they're under "Debug - Windows"